# How to create a Mac service to insert UUIDs into Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, service, uuid, automator

I'm trying to use Automator to create a service that inserts UUIDs into Xcode. Here's what I got:

[image: service]

Presumably, if you highlight some text in source code then choose *Xcode Menu | Services | Generate UUID*, it will replace highlighted text with the UUID. It doesn't do anything.

What am I missing?